# Android-Сохранение Bitmap на SD карту через AsyncTask не удается

Tags: android, изображения, android-asynctask, usb, sd

У меня в ресурсах есть изображения, которые нужно сохранить на SD карту. Приложение открывает список, я выбираю нужные изображения, после нажатия на кнопку они должны быть записаны на карту.

[image: Это вид MainActivity]

Это код `onClick`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        if (checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
            imageIndex = new ImageIndex(); //ImageIndex-класс с единственным полем index, который резервирует индексы нажатых флажков.
            imageIndex.index = i;
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) (images[i].getDrawable())).getBitmap();
            SaveImageTask saveImageTask = new SaveImageTask();
            saveImageTask.execute(bitmap); //Передаем в AsyncTask
        }
}
```

А дальше выбранные изображения передаются в метод `doInBackground`

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();

            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
            dir.mkdirs(); //Место нахождения карты

            String fileName = imageIndex.index + ""; //Зарезервированный индекс нажатого флажка используется в качестве имени для изображения.
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            outStream.write(imageBytes);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Подключаю USB к телефону. Все идет без ошибок, но на моей SD карте изображения не сохраняются. Отладка также не дает ответа. В чем может быть причина?

[image: Отладка приложения]

Comment: У вас есть соответствующие разрешения в манифесте? Обратите внимание, что для android 6.0 и выше необходимо еще дополнительно их запрашивать.

Comment: Да, в манифесте добавлено
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

даже не знаю. На первый взгляд ошибки действительно не видно. В таких случаях часто проще написать заново. Вот например как я сохраняю. Тут если не сохранит, то о крайней мере должен выкинуть ошибку. Попробуйте это. Если не получится, то будем разбираться дальше.

```
 public static void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

            String path = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
            File myDir = new File(path);
            myDir.mkdirs();

            String fname = "Image-" + ваш индекс+ ".jpg";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Снова та же ситуация. Может быть нужны еще какие нибудь разрешения?

Comment: Можно добавить на всякий случай еще     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> А какая у вас версия андроид?

Comment: Lenovo Android 5.0, API 21

Comment: Откровенно странно... Права вы запрашиваете при запуске приложения? Там где пользователь подтверждает. И последний вопрос, вы пытаетесь сохранить во внутреннюю память или на sd card?

Comment: Нет, не запрашиваю..
Я пытаюсь сохранить на SD карту.

Comment: Вот скорее всего в том и беда. Что на SD карту. В андроид >= киткат проблемы с картой. Попробуйте сначала во внутреннюю сохранить.

Comment: Все выяснил. Изображения появляются в галлерее только после перезагрузки телефона.